# are there any decidable problems not verifiable in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

As I understand it NP requires a solution to be verifiable in polynomial time. Can you provide examples of solvable problems not verifiable in polynomial time ?

Comment: Even though I answered, note that this is a bad question. What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't understand why it is a bad question (please explain). The question following that comment makes no sense to me. I have not tried anything and have not gotten stuck anywhere. I asked the question because the definitions of NP (and P) that I have seen all require poly-time verifiability and I wanted to know if there were problems for which solutions are not poly-time verifiable and thus outside NP, and if so, an example.

Comment: Exactly: you have not tried anything on your own. [We don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/627/reference-templates-for-common-comments/751#751).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given input $x = \langle M \rangle$, decide whether $M$ halts after $|x|!$ steps on input $x$.

Comment: Quite anticlimactic.

Comment: @ZeroUltimax At least it's an example; I *could* have gone with citing the "there are arbitrarily hard problems" theorem. ;D

Comment: Could you provide a link where I can find out more about the  "there are arbitrarily hard problems" theorem please? To avoid upsetting anyone, I have tried googling ([1](https://www.google.es/#q=%22there%2Bare%2Barbitrarily%2Bhard%2Bproblems%22), [2](https://www.google.es/#q=there+are+arbitrarily+hard+problems))
but I didn't find anything I recognise as an answer.

Comment: @user533933 It's the quite well-known [time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) (in one or the other form).

Comment: @Raphael But there is no proof that time hierarchy does not collapse, right?

Comment: @bellpeace Read again; the time hiearchy with *proper* inclusions is a *proven theorem*. You may have the [polynomial hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy) in mind, which is a different thing. In particular, it sets deterministic and non-deterministic classes in relation (which is what the whole P!=NP business is about) which the time hierarchy does neither do nor need.

Comment: Yes, I had a wrong hierarchy in mind. My bad.

Comment: I am unable to find a proof for that a solution to the problem provided by @Raphael in answer to my question is "not **verifiable** in polynomial time" (as required by my question). Is that actually proven?

Comment: @user533933 What would a certificate/witness be here?